# Convert Unicode to UTF8

Tags: javascript, unicode, utf-8

I am trying to mashup two different 3rd party services in javascript and I am getting strings in a certain character set, that I need to convert to a different character set in Javascript.

For example, the string is tést.

I am given an encoded string like this: te%u0301st.  The accent is encoded as %u0301. I need to somehow convert this to this string: t%C3%A9st where the é is encoded as %C3%A9.  How can I convert e%u0301 to %C3%A9 in javascript?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide more information on the input encoding? It looks like you're trying to produce URI-encoded UTF-8 (given the percent encoding of the UTF-8 octets). What is the format of the input string? `%u` followed by 4 hex digits, 4-6 hex digits? Or are you just trying to represent the fact that you have a string, in Javascript, with the Unicode codepoint U+0301? And are you intentionally trying to normalize the string as well as transcoding it (changing from combining accents to precomposed characters)?

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be trying to normalize your input, probably in Unicode Normal Form C. I do not know of any simple way to do this in Javascript; you may need to implement the [normalization algorithm](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/) yourself, or find a library which does so.

**edited to remove answer to the wrong question**

Comment: I actually get the string as "tést".  It is only upon running escape() on it that I can see that the é is encoded with the %u unicode code point.  I need to somehow convert the encoding of the string in such a way that running escape() on it produces the %C3 encoding instead.  I apologize that I dont know the correct terminology for the final encoding that I need.  I essentially still need the string to be "tést", but I need the é to encoded differently.  Does that make sense?   I tried running your code, but it just converted it around in a circle back to the same thing I had before.

Comment: @Jake Ah, OK. I was mistaken in what you were trying to do. It sounds like you are actually just trying to normalize your strings in Normal Form C, not escape or unescape them (you were just using that to demonstrate what actual codepoints occurred in the string).

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is *any* URL-escaped Unicode encoding, this will do the trick:

```
function convert(s) {
  function parse(a, c) {
    return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(c, 16));
  }
  return encodeURIComponent(s.replace(/%u([0-f]{4})/gi, parse));
}

convert('te%u0301st'); // => te%CC%81st
```

If you specifically need Normal Form C, you need to implement a whole lot of Unicode intelligence yourself, as `'te\u0301st'.length` (or `'tést'.length`) is 5 in javascript.